# AS3 TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null

Tags: actionscript-3

TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null.

I am working on a game right now and trying to get it so the player will collide with the ground (he already collides with table)

It says the problem is happening in playerOneCollisions

table and ground are just classes with the basic class code linked to movieclips,
they are extended movieclips (if that matters), and they have imported stage and movieclip (again, if that matters)

**(the parts I think are important)**

**Player.as**

```
public var main:Main;
public var table:Table;
public var player:Player;
public var ground:Ground;

        public function playerOneCollisions(table, ground)
        {
            if(this.hitTestObject(table))
            {
                trace("tabled");
                animation = "kong";
            }
            if(this.hitTestObject(ground))
            {
                trace("grounded");
                animation = "idle";
            }
        }
```

**The function playerOneCollisions is called in Main.as**

```
public function GameClock(timerEvent:TimerEvent):void
        {
            player.playerOnePress();
            player.playerOneKeyResults();
            player.playerOneCollisions(table, ground);
            player.playerAnimaitons();
        }
```

**The rest of the code incase I was wrong about the important parts**

**Player.as**

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import KeyObject;
    import Table;

    public class Player extends MovieClip
    {
        public var stageRef:Stage;
        public var key:KeyObject;
        public var main:Main;
        public var table:Table;
        public var player:Player;
        public var ground:Ground;       

        public var leftPressed:Boolean = false;
        public var rightPressed:Boolean = false;
        public var upPressed:Boolean = false;
        public var downPressed:Boolean = false;

        public var grounded:Boolean = false;

        public var animation:String = "idle";

        public var runSpeed:Number = 5;

        public var animationState:String = "idle";

        public function Player (stageRef:Stage, X:int, Y:int):void
        {
            this.stageRef = stageRef;
            this.x = X;
            this.y = Y;

            key = new KeyObject(stageRef);
        }
        public function playerOnePress()
        {
            if(key.isDown(37) || key.isDown(65)){ // if left arrow or A is pressed
                leftPressed = true;
                //trace("left pressed");
            } else {
                leftPressed = false;
            }

            if(key.isDown(38) || key.isDown(87)){ // if up arrow or W is pressed
                upPressed = true;
                //trace("up pressed");
            } else {
                upPressed = false;
            }

            if(key.isDown(39) || key.isDown(68)){ //if right arrow or D is pressed
                rightPressed = true;
                //trace("right pressed");
            } else {
                rightPressed = false;
            }

            if(key.isDown(40) || key.isDown(83)){ //if down arrow or S is pressed
                downPressed = true;
                //trace("down pressed");
            } else {
                downPressed = false;
            }
        }
        public function playerOneKeyResults()
        {
            if(leftPressed)
            {
//              trace("left");
                this.x -= runSpeed;
            }else if(rightPressed)
            {
//              trace("right");
                this.x += runSpeed;
            }
        }
        public function playerOneCollisions(table, ground)
        {
            if(this.hitTestObject(table))
            {
                trace("tabled");
                animation = "kong";
            }
            if(this.hitTestObject(ground))
            {
                trace("grounded");
                animation = "idle";
            }
        }
        public function playerAnimaitons()
        {
            if(animation == "kong")
            {
                this.gotoAndStop(2);
            }
            if(animation == "idle")
            {
                this.gotoAndStop(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Main.as**

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.utils.Timer;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        public var gameTimer:Timer;
        public var player:Player;
        public var table:Table;
        public var ground:Ground;

        public function Main():void
        {
            gameTimer = new Timer (30);
            gameTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, GameClock);
            gameTimer.start();

            player = new Player(stage, 80, 420);
            stage.addChild(player);
        }
        public function GameClock(timerEvent:TimerEvent):void
        {
            player.playerOnePress();
            player.playerOneKeyResults();
            player.playerOneCollisions(table, ground);
            player.playerAnimaitons();
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I notice is that you have `table` and `ground` as class properties of `Player`, and they are also parameters for the method you are having trouble with.

The `table` and/or `ground` properties of your Player class are likely null as I don't see code that sets them.

It's not good practice to have method parameters named the same as your class properties.

Try removing the properties in your Player class. (I don't see them being set or used)

If you still get the error, trace out their values at the beginning of the `playerOneCollisions` method and ensure they are not null.

If they are null, the problem exists outside this class and you are passing in a null value.

I should also note that I don't see anywhere in the Main class where you set the `table` or `ground` properties, so they are null unless you have not shown us all the code. If they are null, then that will certainly cause the issue you are experiencing.

Comment: when I trace table and ground it says  [Object Table] and null for the ground, so table is fine, but ground isn't.  I am pretty sure I did them the same

Comment: Right, so the problem is that you are passing a null value into that function. You don't show us the code where you assign ground a value. Thats where you need to be looking as my answer noted at the bottom.

Comment: I guess I don't really understand, I thought that was what I did up near the top of main.as with, public var ground:Ground;  at least it worked for table, and I really don't think I did anything different, at least that I noticed

Comment: Declaration of a variable does not assign a value, so both those variables will be null by default after you declare them. Next question is are these instances on your stage timeline ? If so, do you properly have the instances named ?

Comment: how do I assign it value?  Also, now my table is having the same problem even though I changed nothing

Comment: If you need help assigning a value to a variable, I think it'd be best if you took a step back and find a tutorial on basic programming concepts.

Comment: I get how it is usually supposed to work, but it doesn't here, no matter how I try it

Comment: It's likely that table/ground are instances on the stage in your fla, and you have not named those instances. If you don't name them, they won't be accessible via your code.

Comment: I know I am supposed to avoid thank you comments, but seriously thank you, that was the problem.  I didn't know I had to name the instance because I thought it was implied by the "instance of:" part

Comment: Well, "instance of:" is the correct way to look at it. An instance is one of potentially many instances of a given 'Symbol'. So therefore, you need to be able to distinguish between those instances, right ?

Comment: It's important to note that if you name an instance on the stage, you don't need to declare it as a property in your document class. That is what was confusing about your code, as I'm sure most of us were thinking the table and ground were classes you created or auto-generated classes of a library symbol, not instances on your stage. Like your player instance, you created an instance of the Player class that is linked to a library symbol for your player.